# ThreadPoolExecutor's submit() method block if it is saturated?

Tags: java

If i extend ThreadPoolExecutor and override execute to have workQueue.put(command) instead of offer(command). Will this help?

Answer (score -1):

It will help if that is what you need, or perhaps it won't really fix your true problem.  It is also possible this will just make your code more complicated for no defined benefit.

It all depends on your situation, which is why this is not done by default.

What I consider a better alternative is to have the current thread execute the task if the queue is full.

Comment: Problem with that is if my tasks take much time then calling thread will be busy for sometime , meanwhile my pool threads will have no other task to perform.

Comment: @AbhishekAgarwal Are you saying that your queue can go from full to empty, while the main thread is executing a task?  Can you not increase the queue size so this doesn't happen?

Comment: We are more concerned that no task should be lost due to server failure or so. Therefore we are only keeping no. of msgs = threads .

Comment: If you don't want to lose messages you have to persist them before you start. Having no of msgs = threads reduces the number you could lose, but in the end still means you could lose them.